# Sql query which returns multiple rows matching criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have a survey system which the following `questionanswer` table

```
questionId personId response
1             a       red
2             a       blue
3             a       green
4             a       black
1             b       red
2             b       blue
3             b       green
4             b       black
```

I need to construct a query for a search form allowing users to pick the question and the response to be returned.  i.e. the user may pick `question 1 answer = red` and `question 3 and answer green`

I have to return those `personId`'s that match that criteria (in the above table it would return a and b)

`psuedo: select from questionanswer table all personId's where question=1 && answer=red AND those personId's where question=3 and answer was green`

This code would run after the administrator selects 'search'  returning back distinct a and b personId's

(seems simple but i must be missing something?)

Comment: I see you've posted some pseudo code, but what actual SQL have you tried and what was incorrect about the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you passing in the QuestionIds and Responses? Let's assume you eventually get them into a table variable:

```
    DECLARE @Search TABLE 
    ( questionId int, 
      response varchar(30) )
```

Then your SQL then becomes:

```
    SELECT q.personID
    FROM questionanswertable AS q
    INNER JOIN @Search AS s
    ON s.questionId = q.questionId
       AND s.response = q.response
    GROUP BY q.personID
    HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @Search)
```

Comment: Trying this approach as it may work.  I found that it returns results like there is an OR between the different rows in the search table
 
 
Using your code i created the @search table and inserted in the following rows
1 red                  (should act like AND between these rows)

3 gggggreeeen


With those values there are no rows that match both those criteria's and so nothing should be returned.  In fact it return any rows where any of those rows matched.

Comment: Sorry, I did think you wanted an OR. I changed my answer to be an AND for all the search responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT personID
FROM questionanswertable 
WHERE (questionID = 1 AND response = 'red')
OR (questionID = 3 AND response = 'green')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT personID
FROM questionanswertable 
WHERE questionID = 3 AND response = 'green' AND personID in (
    SELECT DISTINCT personID
    FROM questionanswertable
    WHERE (questionID = 1 AND response = 'red'))
```

Comment: JBrooks may be closer as the number of questions and responses is dynamice (from a search page where the user can pick as many questions/responses as desired)...not sure if this is dynamic enough

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT personId
FROM questionanswer
WHERE questionId IN(SELECT questionId FROM questionanswer WHERE questionId = 1 AND response = 'red')
AND questionId IN(SELECT questionId FROM questionanswer WHERE questionId = 3 AND response = 'green')
```